# EM's for line-height

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I would like to convert my new website from pixels to ems. My question is, should I also apply ems to my text line-height property?

Comment: Yes, you can. `em` is a valid unit for CSS `line-height` property

Comment: The accepted answer points out why one should NOT use any unit with line-height: because line-height is then calculated only ONCE and the result is inherited. To have line-height adjust with font-sizes, remove the unit.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assuming that “converting to ems” means using the `em` unit for `font-size`, then you should set `line-height` in a manner that also adapts to the font size. The two properties are closely related, and if you set one of them in `em` and the other (e.g.) in `px` or `pt`, then the page will break if the font size is changed. So it would work against the very idea of “using ems” to use essentially different units for essentially connected properties.

For example, if you set `font-size: 1.5em` and `line-height: 18px`, then things will depend on the font size of the element’s parent and may go very wrong if that size is much smaller or much larger than expected.

Whether you use the `em` unit or a pure number is a different issue. Using just a number, as in `line-height: 1.2`, is primarily equivalent to using the `em` unit, as in `line-height: 1.2em`. But there is the difference that when `line-height` is inherited, it is the pure number that gets inherited, not the computed value.

For example, if an inner element has twice the font size of its parent, then the inherited value `1.2` means that 1.2 times its own font size is used, which is OK. But if the parent had `line-height: 1.2em`, then the child would inherit a value that 1.2 times the parent’s font size – which is much smaller than its own font size.

for more explanation end examples see [line-height @ Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height)

Comment: Thanks for the difference between `line-height: 1.5em` and `line-height: 1.5`, it saved me a lot of searching!

Answer (score 8):

`line-height` can be set in `px`, `em`'s, every unit will fit.

`line-height` works best and future proof if you use a factor/multiplier, meaning no unit, but only a number that is multiplying your font-size.

```
.foo {
  font-size: 1.3em; /* based that 1em == 10px */
  line-height: 1.3; /* 16.9px line-height */
}
```

So, Yes, you can, to answer you question: no you should not.

just go for the factor based line-height to be future proof.

Comment: Is it recommended to convert line-height to ems if I use ems for my font-size?

Answer (score 6):

It is recommended to use the unitless number for line-height (to prevent inheritance issues). The computed line-height will then be **the product of the unitless value multiplied by the element's font size**.

It may be more convenient to use the `font` CSS shortcut, like so (example taken from the Mozilla CSS docs):

```
div { font: 10pt/1.2  Georgia,"Bitstream Charter",serif }
```

A good example of why the unitless value is preferable is given here: [Prefer unitless numbers for line-height values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values).

Comment: Great tip and MDN resource! I always wondered about the `line-height` property and the intricasies of `em`s. With that link and the background on [ems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems), I came out a lot wiser.