# Rem unit size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with rem unit in CSS. In my current project all sizes are rem. When I set an element size (like div), the displayed size is 16 px * (x) ems. But when a div contains text or headings, the displayed size is 19 * (x) ems. This happens in Chrome, FF and IE. Here's an example:

html

```
<header id="header">
<h1 id="header-title">Blablabla</h1>
<h2 id="header-subtitle">LOL</h2>
</header>
```

css

```
#header {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
}

#header-subtitle {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Why?

**EDIT**:
I've not declared line-height, by default it was 12.5px. I've searched more and I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135142/3552129

Comment: I see no difference in size between when the headings are in the header and when they are not: http://jsfiddle.net/2a7xf/1/

Comment: You should make sure that you set the `html` css  class correctly: i.e. `html {font-size: 14px;}`  using pixels or fixed size so that the `rem` (root em) has a root value to use which its self is not a relative size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EM's for line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132671/ems-for-line-height)