# Do REMs always come from font-size in html?

Tags: css

Let's say I have:

```
html {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Will the padding in the div then be 4px (so from `padding` in `html{}`) or 10px (form `font-size` in `html{}`)?

Comment: `Do REMs always come from font-size in html?` Yes, It does. Hence the computed value of `padding` of the `div` would be `0.5 * 20px` = `10px`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263790/rem-unit-size-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS Values and Unites Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-values-20120308/#font-relative-lengths) states:

> ### rem unit
>
> Equal to the computed value of `font-size` on the root element. When specified on the `font-size` property of the root element, the `rem` units refer to the property’s initial value.

You can try this yourself by inspecting your `div` element and looking at the computed values:

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, world!</div>
```

[image: Example]

So yes, as we can see, the `padding` has been computed at `10px` - half the `font-size`.