# Line height is different for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I designed a close icon, but they appear different in Firefox and Chrome. I set the same line-height same as the height, it's working for Firefox but not for Chrome. I have been faced this issue before for different elements but I didn't get it.

Here is code:

```
.careerClose {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #dc3545;
}
```

If I set `line height 32px`, then it's looking good in Chrome. I also tried `line-height 1.2`.And both two browsers are up-to-date.

Below image view for Firefox.
[image]

Below image view for Chrome.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303169/line-height-without-units

Comment: Each browser has its own default values so you need to override them.